# Difference between Deep Insert and $batch OData

Tags: odata

Can any one tell me the difference between usage of Deep Insert and $batch - ChangeSet in the context of OData ? I have a scenario that requires creation of a Sales Order Header and Sales Order Items together.

- I can either user Deep Insert (BTW is this standard OData spec ?) or
- I can use a $batch (this is standard OData spec) call with these two entities specified as a part of the same ChangeSet, which would ensure that they get saved together as a part of a single LUW.

What are the pros / cons of using either of these approaches ? Any experiences ?
Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deep Insert is part of the OData specification, see http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793718.

Deep Insert allows creating a tree of related entities in one request. It is insert only.

$batch allows grouping arbitrary requests into one request, and arbitrary modifying operations into LUWs (called change sets).

For insert-only cases Deep Insert is easier: you just POST the same format that you would GET with $expand.

Comment: Off-topic but are you still active in SO? Would be nice if the community could have answers directly from you. E.g.https://stackoverflow.com/q/59837206/5846045

Answer (score 1):

Deep insert or deep update is not currently defined and supported by OData spec. However there are such feature requests, like this: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4416931-odata-deep-update-request-support

If you decided to use a batch, then you have to do the next set of commands in your batch:

- PUT SalesOrderItem
- ...
- PUT SalesOrderItem
- PUT SalesOrderHeader
- PUT SalesOrderHeader/links$/SalesOrderItem
- ...
- PUT SalesOrderHeader/links$/SalesOrderItem

See also here: [How do I update an OData entity and modify its navigation properties in one request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604673/how-do-i-update-an-odata-entity-and-modify-its-navigation-properties-in-one-requ)

In our ASP.NET project we decided to go with CQRS pattern and use OData for Query requests and Web API for Commands. Talking in terms of your case we created Web API Controller with action CreateSalesOrder with parameter of class SalesOrderHeaderDto that contains array of SalesOrderItemDtos. Having the data on server you can easily develop insert the whole Order Sale in one transaction with its Order Items. Also there is just two command to be sent on server - ~/api/CreateSalesORder and ~/odata/SalesOrder with include=Items and filter by something... for example first command can return an Id of the Order...

Answer (score 0):

Deep insert gives one operation that will insert all the items as one operation.

The same thing isn't possible in a $batch. 
This is not automatic in a batch :

> they get saved together as a part of a single LUW

The $batch needs to be in a single change set to expect atomicity. 
According to [OData 4.0 11.7.4 Responding to a Batch Request](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752317):

> All operations in a change set represent a single change unit so a service MUST successfully process and apply all the requests in the change set or else apply none of them. It is up to the service implementation to define rollback semantics to undo any requests within a change set that may have been applied before another request in that same change set failed and thereby apply this all-or-nothing requirement. The service MAY execute the requests within a change set in any order and MAY return the responses to the individual requests in any order. The service MUST include the Content-ID header in each response with the same value that the client specified in the corresponding request, so clients can correlate requests and responses.

However, a single changeset is [**unordered**](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752316). Given you are doing a deep insert, there is **some** realtionship between the entities, and given you are doing an insert, in either a contained navigation or a $ref navigation you can't perform both inserts or both inserts and the PUT / POST $ref in an unordered fashion.

> A change set is an atomic unit of work consisting of an unordered group of one or more Data Modification requests or Action invocation requests.