# WCF Data Services deep insert how to

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I went through many posts here, but still can´t find a way how to do a deep insert with WCF Data Services and DataServiceContext. I don´t want BATCH. I really need deep insert. There was a comment in one old post:

> So called deep updates (which is what you want here) are not supported
> by WCF Data Services. In fact even OData itself doesn't really define
> it. It can get rather complicated as to what it means in some cases.
> I'm afraid batch is the only solution for this. Deep inserts are
> supported (but again only inserts, not modifying anything existing)
> though. – Vitek Karas MSFT Sep 26 '12 at 20:14
> [How do I update an OData entity and modify its navigation properties in one request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604673/how-do-i-update-an-odata-entity-and-modify-its-navigation-properties-in-one-requ)

**Deep inserts are supported!**

But how to do that?

There was a coude in a post before, so it fits my case to. It goes something like this:

```
    var item1 = new Item { CODE = "ABC1", NAME = "A B C 1" };
var item2 = new Item { CODE = "ABC2", NAME = "A B C 2" };
var items = new DataServiceCollection<Item >{ item1, item2 };
var mt    = new MyType { CURRDATE = DateTime.Now.toString(), ITEMS = items };
_container.AddToMyType(mt);
var resp = _container.SaveChanges();
//...etc
```

But it triggers an exeption:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: An item could
> not be added to the collection. When items in a DataServiceCollection
> are tracked by the DataServiceContext, new items cannot be added
> before items have been loaded into the collection."

Any idea?

Comment: The last exception is saying you first have to query the database and put data into the context before trying to insert into the database.

Comment: I don´t understand it. Im creating new items. They are not in DB yet. Should I load an empty query? What should I load?

Comment: You need to load the context.  See the line above the following link.  The loading is part of the connection.  May be you are not calling the constructor properly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#other-dbcontext-constructor-options

Comment: If you create a new DataServiceCollection<T>() (constructor without parameters), it will create the collection in the so-called auto-tracking mode. This link contains similar questions you can refer to it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7204c587-75ac-4470-9bac-c0a553a7fa4b/dataservicecollection-new-items-cannot-be-added-before-items-have-been-loaded-into-the-collection?forum=adodotnetdataservices